# Understanding central limit theorem

Tags: central-limit-theorem

What is wrong with the following sentence:

> The Central Limit Theorem  implies that, as the sample size grows, the error distribution approaches normality.

Am I correct by saying that it should in stead state the MEAN of the sample error approaches zero as sample size grows?

Comment: I meant to say "the distribution of the mean of the sample error approaches zero" Do you agree? Or am I missing the mistake in the statement completely? Thanks for the opinions (in advance)

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific (e.g. the error distribution of...? What model are you using?) but the second thing you said sound closer to the law of large numbers than the CLT.

Comment: The error distribution does not change.

Comment: It depends on what "error distribution" means, Xi'an (and what statistic it refers to, and what kind of asymptotic setting one is in, etc.).  This question is impossible to answer without making (at least some implicit) assumptions about the context.  It would help for the OP to respond to Macro's request for more information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In its standard simplest form, the Central Limit Theorem (CLT) is a statement 
about the cumulative distribution function of the random variable
$$Z_n = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n -n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$$
where the $X_i$ are independent identically distributed random variables
with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.  The CLT asserts that
for each $a$, $-\infty < a < \infty$,
$$F_{Z_n}(a) = P\left\{\frac{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n -n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}
\leq a
\right\} \to \Phi(a) = \int_{-\infty}^a \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm dx$$
as $n \to \infty$.

If by *"error distribution"* you mean the distribution function of
$$Y_n = \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) -\mu
= \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}Z_n,$$
that is, the difference of the sample mean $\bar{X} = n^{-1}\sum_iX_i$ 
and the population mean $\mu$, then the CLT certainly
*does not* imply that $F_{Y_n}(\cdot)$ "approaches normality" as the
sample size $n$ grows large in the
usual sense of normality, though nitpickers may want to claim that the
distribution is approaching a normal distribution with mean $0$ and 
*standard deviation* $0$ (often called a constant by statistically 
illiterate people).

On the other hand, the **mean** of the sample error is **not** a random
variable but a constant (in fact, $0$ since the sample mean is an *unbiased*
estimator of the population mean) and does not need to *approach*
$0$; it is already there!  I think what you meant to say is that the
*distribution* $F_{Y_n}(a)$ of the *sample error* approaches the unit
step function:
$$F_{Y_n}(a) \to u(a) = \begin{cases}1, & \text{if}~a > 0,\\
0 &\text{if}~a < 0,\end{cases}$$
which is certainly correct, and follows from the CLT,
but also follows from results such as
the weak law of large numbers which makes no assertions
about the distribution of $Z_n$, only about $Y_n$.

Comment: (+1) Here is a **fun** nitpick: One needs the extra assumption that $u(a)$ is continuous at $a$ to be able to conclude $F_{Y_n}(a) \to u(a)$, so, in particular, the first inequality ($a \geq 0$) also needs to be strict ($a > 0$), like the second one. A canonical example is to take $X_i$ iid uniform on $\{-1,+1\}$ and show that $F_{Y_n}(0) \to 1/2$. Showing this for the subsequence of *odd* $n$ is easiest (just symmetry), but it's not much harder to show it holds also for the subsequence of even $n$.

Comment: @cardinal You are right; in the interest of brevity, I had skipped stating the part where convergence is guaranteed only at points where $u(\cdot)$ is continuous, and then written the standard CDF description. Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I will fix the statement.

Comment: This is all thew information I was given (old test question). But we focus on OLS models if that makes a difference at all. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @Las You and user9097 (cf. [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22557/6633)) seem to be looking at the same exam! If the question on the exam asks whether the statement "The CLT says the distribution of the sample mean asymptotically converges to a normal distribution" is correct, the answer is NO. If the exam goes on to ask "If you answered NO, what _does_ the CLT say actually?", the answer is that subject to suitable conditions (which you can get from the above), the CLT says that the distribution of $\sqrt{n}\bar{X}$ converge to a normal $\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma)$ distribution.

Comment: Thanks Dilip. That certainly makes more sense to me now.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - Hello Sir! Can you please explain how  the distribution of $\sqrt{n}\bar{X}$ converges to a normal $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$. If by $\bar{X}$ you meant sample mean then would not the distribution be $\mathcal{N}(\sqrt{n}\mu,\sigma^2)$?