# Does the central limit theorem imply the law of large numbers

Tags: mathematical-statistics, central-limit-theorem

Assuming that the distribution has finite variance (a condition not required for the LLN), then doesn't the LLN follow from the CLT?

Comment: Possibly of interest: [central-limit-theorem-versus-law-of-large-numbers](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22557/).

Answer (score 7):

WLLN, yes.

Here is a general claim: Suppose $\{ f_n \}$, $f$, and $g$ are random variables, and

$$
\sqrt{n} (f_n - f) \stackrel{d}{\mapsto} g.
$$

Let's say the CDF of $g$ is continuous everywhere. Then $f_n \rightarrow f$ in probability. This is because $\sqrt{n} (f_n - f)$ is bounded in probability/uniformly tight.