# Testing for difference between two percentages (using confidence intervals)

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, proportion

I wish to test for whether the difference between 2 percentages is significantly different. For each percentage there are associated confidence intervals, which I need to incorporate into the test (CI reflect the accuracy of the estimated percentage).

Comment: I don't know which statistical software you use, but in `R`, this can be easily tested using `prop.test`. For example: `prop.test(x=c(50,20), n=c(100, 70), conf.level=0.95)`. In any case: a quick [Google search](https://www.google.ch/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=difference+two+proportions&oq=difference+two+proportions&gs_l=hp.3..0i22i30l4.56.2513.0.2591.26.18.0.4.4.1.187.2316.0j17.17.0...0.0.0..1c.1.17.psy-ab.NARKYF72C_0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48340889,d.bGE&fp=2f99562ada0f7597&biw=1920&bih=955) might reveil helpful pages.

Comment: Very closely related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41156/algebra-for-data-confidence.  That thread shows how to combine the confidence intervals to obtain an interval for the difference; if that interval does not cover zero, you have a significant result. That thread also explains what additional information you need to know or assume in order to make this an answerable question.