# How to get exact distribution of estimated p for binomial distribution?

Tags: distributions, self-study, estimation, binomial-distribution

This question is kind of a follow up of another question I had: [Asymptotic normal distribution via the central limit theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73830/asymptotic-normal-distribution-via-the-central-limit-theorem)

There I had to calculate the estimator for $p$ (meaning $p$ for success) and approximate it's distribution by approximation with a normal distribution.

Now I would like to get the exact distribution of $p$.

I got already the following hint: "You have the functional form of $\hat{p}$. Look up how we derive the distribution of a function of a discrete random variable." Unfortunately that did not lead me to a solution...

Comment: You know that $\hat{p}=X/n$ where $X\sim Bin(n,p)$. So you know the distribution of $X$. What does that tell you about the distribution of $X/n$?

Comment: If you had a binomial variable, $X\sim \text{bin}(n,p)$, could your write its probability function, $\text{P}(X=x)$? Now let $Y = 2X$. Can you write the p.f. for $Y$? Now let $Z = cX$; can you write the p.f. for $Z$? What if $c=\frac{1}{n}$?