# Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, how can I find $P(T(X)>200)$?

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with $\mu$ unknown and $\sigma = 2$ known. Letting $T(X) = \sum{(X_i-\mu)^2}$ from i = 1 to 40, how can I use the central limit theorem to approximate $P(T(X)>200)$?

I found that $E(T(X))=40$ and $Var(T(X))=160$ and $T(X)$ ~ Chi square with n=40 df.

The below is the correct answer, but I do not know how this makes sense since my understanding of the central limit theorem is that the average of iid random variables is normal, but how am I utilizing the central limit below? Thanks!!!!

[image]

Comment: How on earth did you determine that $E[T(X)]$ has value $40$? It should have value $40\sigma^2=160$ as used in the handwritten solution.

Comment: Central limit theorem relates to to mean, not sum. So $T(x)=\frac{1}{40}\sum (X_i-\mu)^2$ would be normally distributed

Comment: @Sachin_ruk You mean to say that if $\frac{1}{40}Z$ is normally distributed, then $Z$ is _not_ normally distributed? And _which_ sum does the CLT apply to? If $Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_n$ are iid standard normal random variables, does the CLT say that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i Z_i \sim N(0,1)$ in the limit as $n \to \infty$ or does it restrict itself to  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_i Z_i$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate but the variable is not normally distributed anymore i.e. $(X_i-\mu)^2$ is not normally distributed, $X_i$ is.

Comment: @Sachin_ruk You are missing the point of my remark. Your statement about the CLT applying to the mean, not the sum, is what the complaint is about. **The CLT does not say anything about the mean or the sum.** Read [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22532/6633) before you insist that it does. Here is an edited version of what I should have written.  "If $Z_1,Z_2,\ldots,Z_n$ are iid zero-mean unit-variance random variables, does the CLT say that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i Z_i \sim N(0,1)$ in the limit as $n\to \infty$ or does it restrict itself to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_i Z_i$?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the answer pointed to by a comment on the question, the Central Limit Theorem examines sums of random variables from which we subtract the mean of the sum and then divide the whole by the standard deviation of the sum: let $Y_1,...,Y_n$ be random variables and define $S_n \equiv \sum_{i=1}^nY_i$. Then the CLT examines the random variable

$$Z_n = \frac {S_n - E[S_n]}{\sqrt {\text {Var}(S_n)}}$$

In its most basic variant, the $Y_i$'s are identically and independently distributed, with existing / finite moments. In such a case, with common mean $\mu$ and common variance $\sigma^2$ we have
$$Z_n = \frac {S_n - n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt n }$$

Given its conditions (which are usually sufficient but not necessary), the CLT asserts that $Z_n \rightarrow_d N(0,1)$ and therefore it provides a result related to the limiting distribution function of $Z_n$ as $n$ goes very-very far away.

So in order to have the "right" to apply the CLT in your case, you have first to show that you do have a $Z_n$-variable to deal with, and that this variable satisfies the conditions that are sufficient for the CLT (or that it does not satisfy the sufficient conditions but nevertheless obeys the CLT -there are such cases).
So define the random variable

$$Y_i = \frac {X_i-\mu}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1) \Rightarrow Y_i^2 \sim \chi^2(1)$$
with $E(Y_i^2) =1$ and $\text{Var}(Y_i^2) =2$. So a "$Z_n$" variable here would be

$$Z_n = \frac {\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i^2 - n}{\sqrt{2n}} = \frac {T(X) - n\sigma^2}{\sigma^2\sqrt{2n}}$$

and using $\sigma^2 = 4$ we get

$$Z_n = \frac {T(X) - 4n}{4\sqrt{2n}} $$

You should verify that the CLT applies for this $Z_n$ variable (it does).
Therefore

$$\frac {T(X) - 4n}{4\sqrt{2n}} = Z_n \rightarrow_d N(0,1)$$

The approximation comes now and consists in "ignoring" that the above distributional result holds asymptotically (i.e. for $n\rightarrow \infty$), and using it for finite $n$. In your case $n = 40$, plug it in and get your results.

**ADDENDUM**
Responding to a comment, note that $X_i-\mu \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and so $(X_i-\mu)^2 \sim \text{Gamma}(1/2, 2\sigma^2)$ and so $T(X) \sim \text{Gamma}(n/2, 2\sigma^2)$ exactly. Then one can calculate the desired probability by inserting the value $200$ in the **Survival function** of the $\text{Gamma}(20, 8)$ distribution (shape-scale parametrization).

Comment: While this is a great answer and it satisfies the OP.  Why in the world would you want to use a normal approximation at n=40 when you have at your disposal the exact distribution! As others point out it is obtained by using the appropriate chi-square distribution. Also the desired result was to calculate P(T(X)>200) which also can be obtained exactly rather than approximately through the normal approximation.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Well, It's been more than two and a half years... I guess it is because the OP asked explicitly "how can I use the CLT to...". I should have mentioned though that $T(X)$ has an exact Gamma distribution... and I am going to do it right now! Thanks!

Comment: Wrong guess. I found this.  It was on a Community bot generated list.  So I clicked on it read everything.  As I was reading the question I could see there was an exact answer and could not understand why the OP was insisting on using the central limit theorem to get the answer(s).  I really appreciate that you went to all the trouble to show the conditions met to use the central limit theorem.  You were the only one to do it. Not necessary but it is nice that added the Addendum just now.  Since this question could get more attention you may get upvotes. I gave you 1.

Answer (score 5):

Try letting $Y_i = (X_i - \mu)^2$ for $i = 1,\ldots, 40$. Then what are $E(Y_i)$ and Var$(Y_i)$ equal to? You should be able to work it out using the CLT from there. Also, note that $T(X)$ does not have a Chi-Square distribution with 40 degrees of freedom. But $T(X)/4$ does since it is the sum of squares of Standard independent normal random variables.